# NullPointerException when getting Integer from TreeMap and assigning to int

Tags: java, dictionary

Am I correctly assuming that these two examples are the only ones that will throw a NullPointerException when getting from a TreeMap and trying to assign the result to a primitive int?

```
TreeMap<BigDecimal, Integer> map = new TreeMap<>();

BigDecimal b = null;
int a = map.get(b);

BigDecimal bb = new BigDecimal("1"); //non existant key
int aa = map.get(bb);
```

I assume the map can either return null due to non-existant key, which then will throw an exception due to implicit .intValue() auto-unboxing - or, throw an exception because the get argument is null itself.

Comment: Your first assumption is correct. `Map.get()` will never throw an NPE just because the key provided is `null` (and it can't be `null` anyway, you've just constructed a non-null key the line before). The only thing that could also be `null`, is `map` itself.

Comment: Please give me more than 0.1 sec after publishing before downvoting and complaining about typos.

Comment: @biziclop The `TreeMap#get()` method will throw `NPE` if key passed as argument is `null`.

Comment: @user3607022 Isn't the [javadoc of `TreeMap`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/TreeMap.html#get(java.lang.Object)) self explanatory about this?

Comment: @biziclop Javadoc says it throws "NullPointerException - if the specified key is null and this map uses natural ordering, or its comparator does not permit null keys"

Comment: @RohitJain You're right, if it's instantiated without a comparator, it will. (At the time of the first comment, this wasn't obvious.) But even if it did accept `null` values, you'd get another NPE on unboxing.

Comment: Both get-calls will throw NPE - correct? The question is---- are these the only cases where getting an Integer and assigning it to an int will throw a NPE

Comment: I am stating two cases where a TreeMap<Integer, Object> get-call will throw a NPE, and I am wondering if anyone knows another case. The first one is obvious, documented in Javadoc. The second case is not so obvious since is stems from implicit Integer unboxing. If there is no other case, I'd be happy to know that for sure. If there might be another case, I'd be happy to know that for sure.

Comment: The confusion with your question is that your intentions / reasoning behind asking are not clear. Enumerating all NPE possibilities is pretty general question, even with such simple code. We are more used to specific questions like "Why am I observing NPE when it should not happen."

Comment: @PavelHoral I would guess NPE from "getting from a TreeMap and trying to assign the result to a primitive int" can be reduced to a reasonable number of cases.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are at least 5 reasons why `int a = map.get(b);` could throw a `NullPointerException`

1. `map == null`
2. `b == null` and `map` doesn't support `null` keys.
3. `map.containsKey(b) == false`
4. `map.containsKey(b) == true` and `map.get(b) == null`
5. The `Comparator` or `compareTo` method used by `map` throws a NPE for some other reason.

Comment: Many thanks. Case 4 - that throw a NPE only due to implicit unboxing - correct? I'm asking since you didn't specifically mention that the map used a key capable of auto-unboxing.

Comment: Yes it's due to unboxing, but of the value, not the key. Whenever you have a method that returns a boxed primitive type (`Integer`, `Character `etc) and you write e.g. `int a = method()` or `char b = method()` you risk a `NullPointerException` due to unboxing. I often use maps with `Integer` values so I regularly write `Integer a = map.get(b); if (a != null) { // do something with a }`. This deals with the cases 3 and 4 simultaneously.